# How to draw class diagram for this situation

Tags: class, model, diagram

A customer can have multiple orders. An order can contain up to 10 sets. Each set can have either 10 items of the same kind OR 3 groups of different items.
I dont know how to draw diagram for the second part, e.g. sets that can have either 10 items or 3 groups of different items.

Comment: How does your diagram look so far?

Comment: This exact business rules are not fully expressible in terms of class diagram. You should make appropriate (to hold all data and be easy to use) class structure and use runtime checks to enforce limitations, that does not follow from the class structure.

Comment: I have customer-order (1-*) relation. Order to sets (1..10). Set to item (1-10)..and the last part I dont know, these three groups of different items. Maybe Set-group(1-3) and Group-item (1*n)?

Comment: Do you think, things like order (1..10) really mean something?? You can draw them, but your target language will not support them, so really you will get usual (1..*) And the difference between (1..*) and (1..10) will be checked only by manually written code.

Comment: THis is about class diagram, nothing else. ANd this is the correct notation..not sure why you question UML notation..

Comment: Ok, I am not questioning UML spec correctness, but I thought you are making diagram to generate maximal useful code from it. If this is about diagram for the diagram, I appologise for my interest and discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

It could be like this
[image]
It indicates `Order` class would have either a list of `Item`, or a reference of `ItemGroup`(where `ItemGroup` has 3 different `Item` lists), but **CAN NOT** HAS BOTH.
in other word, one of the either `singleSet` or `multiSet` variables should be null.


According to UML 2.4.1, section  7.3.10 Constraint (from Kernel)